# What does it mean when I'm cowering in fear?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

In the Kero Sewers, enemy Boos sometimes use a Scream attack that makes one of my party members cower in fear with a purple aura around them. The scared party member can seemingly still fight like normal, so what does this cowering in fear state mean?

[image: Mallow cowering in fear]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Fear)

> When a character is afraid, their attack and defense is cut in half, meaning they deal only half damage to enemies and receive approximately fifty percent more damage from enemy attacks.